# Как в Yandex Maps 3.0 получить значение адреса при использовании suggest()?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

В API Яндекс Карт новой версии 3.0 существует метод [suggest()](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/3.0/ref/index.html#suggest), который возвращает строковый набор подсказок.

Ранее в версии 2.1 этот метод возвращал объекты, содержащие поля `displayName` и `value`. Полученный `value` можно было использовать, например, для дальнейшего геокодирования.

В версии 3.0 же метод возвращает только `title` и `subtitle`, которые подходят для отображения в заголовке и подзаголовке подсказки, но при этом в ответе нет поля-аналога `value`, который можно было бы использовать как выбранное значение адреса.
value можно было бы получить манипуляциями над полями `title` и `subtitle`, однако, это небезопасно и также `subtitle` может иметь дополнительные данные, которые не относятся к адресу. В таких случаях этих полей недостаточно.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно получить настоящий `text`/`value` адреса из подсказки?**

Пример, когда необходимо получить значение адреса:

Если передать в метод следующие параметры:

```
ymaps3.suggest({ text: 'Россия, улица вертолетчиков', limit: 10, type: 'toponyms' })
```

в ответе внутри промиса возвращается массив с похожими элементами *(могут добавляться бывшие названия улиц или количество километров до места)*:

```
{
  subtitle: {
    "text": "Москва ·  Бывш. Проектируемый проезд № 6658",
    "hl": []
  },
  title: {
      "text": "улица Вертолётчиков, 13",
      "hl": [[0,5],[6,19]]
  },
}
```

В api v2.1 помимо displayName было так же значение `value : "Москва, улица Вертолётчиков, 13 "`. При этом в самом запросе, отправляемом на сервер видно, что значение `text:  "Москва, улица Вертолётчиков, 13 "` есть, но не прокидывается в ответ метода.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще в консоли видно, что саджест возвращает всё те же данные, что и в версии 2.1, но в функцию suggest передаёт только **subtitle**, **title** и **type**. Видимо, пока остальные поля не имеют стабильного адреса, решили их скрыть и, быть может, вывести в ответ позже, как определятся с формой и форматом. Можно поинтересоваться в поддержке, так ли это, и когда сделают.

А вообще Яндекс вывел [Геосаджест](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geosuggest/) в отдельный сервис. Для получения расширенного ответа имеет смысл использовать именно его.